# How to add PHP variables to a href url

Tags: php, html, href

Im trying to add a PHP variable to a href url

This is the code:

**PHP**

```
$uid= $_SESSION['userid'];
```

**HTML**

```
<a href=http://example.com/uid= <?php echo ".$uid."?> /a>
```

How do you add, when I do it, this is what it redirect too: http://example.com/uid=.

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start()` at the top of your script, and the syntax should look like `<a href="http://example.com/uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>">...</a>`

Comment: Your syntax is broken. You want to get rid of the quotes inside the PHP part (but wrap the entire `href` attribute in them)

Comment: <a href="http://example.com/uid= <?php echo $uid?"></a>

Comment: This depends **ENTIRELY** on how you're using that html. Is it being assigned to a php string? Then echo is the totally wrong tool. Is it direct output "out" of php mode? Then it'd work, if you fixed your html syntax.

Comment: @user3245415 you're supposed to pick the answer that helps you most at some point. Are you still stuck on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
@session_start();
$uid= $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
<a href="http://example.com/?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>" >Your link text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<a href=\"http://example.com/?uid=$uid\">link description</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
print '<a href=http://example.com/?uid=' . $uid . '>Link</a>';
```

Comment: Syntax is wrong - missing closing bracket for a tag and the double-quote isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most helpful

```
echo "<td>".($tripId != null ? "<a target=\"_blank\"href=\"http://www.rooms.com/r/trip/".$tripId."\">".$tripId."</a>" : "-")."</td>";
```

It will work!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>

Or for PHP 5.4+ (<?= is the PHP short echo tag):
<a href="<?= $url ?>">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>

or 
echo '<a href="' . $url . '">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 <a href=http://example.com/?uid= <?php echo $uid ?> Myurl</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href=http://example.com/uid= <?=$uid?> /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple things wrong.

1. In HTML you should quote attribute values such as href
2. In PHP you're not concatenating anything, just echoing
3. You forgot the link text
4. For readability, you can (probably) use the `<?=` shorthand instead of `<?php echo`
5. `<a /a>` is broken tag syntax.  Should be `<a>...</a>`

End result is this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/uid=<?=$uid?>">Link Text</a>
```